# how to check if selector has a "sibling" class

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to find out how to match if a selector has a certain class. for example.

```
<p class="myClass visible">

if($(".myClass").is(".visible")) {
  alert("visible");
}
```

I also tried hasClass, but this doesn't seem to work on same element.

Comment: Your corrected code works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/geary/AWcMJ/

Comment: Are you familiar with the JavaScript developer tools available in most browsers? They would be extremely helpful to you in tracking down these issues. Take any of the fiddles and add a `debugger;` statement at the point in the code where you are uncertain of what is going on. Open the developer tools and load your page. It will stop in the debugger where you can inspect your variables, DOM, etc. You can also try out quick code tests right there in the debugger's JavaScript console. The Chrome dev tools are my favorite: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Also, as I mentioned in another comment, you seem to be mixing up your tagnames and classnames a bit. It's very understandable how this could happen, since - rather confusingly - some of the functions used here require the `.` for a classname and others don't. To help keep it straight: if you are writing a *selector*, as in a `$(...)` call, you need to use the `.` prefix on a classname, just as in any CSS selector. The `.is()` method also takes a selector, so you need the `.`. However, the `.hasClass()` method suggested in some of the answers uses a bare classname *without* the `.` prefix.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I was not familiar with these. I am going to try them now though! thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
if($(".myClass").hasClass("visible")) {
  alert("visible");
}
```

Comment: Have a fiddle to prove your point: http://jsfiddle.net/C3U5n/ :D

Comment: hmm swear I tried this, but it didn't work. Trying in fiddle seems to allow this to work. http://jsfiddle.net/mVLkW/

Comment: ah, it seems that the problem is when I use it in a function: http://jsfiddle.net/mVLkW/4/

Comment: @Lukasz - you're mixing up your tagnames and classnames. Your latest fiddle fails not because of any problem in the `.hasClass()` test and not because that test is in a function, but because of the wrong selector in the `$("myclass")` at the top. You need a dot, and the capitalization doesn't match your HTML. It should be `$(".myClass")`: http://jsfiddle.net/geary/mVLkW/6/ In any case, the corrected version of your original code as now shown in your question is fine! http://jsfiddle.net/geary/AWcMJ/ So why are we still fiddling with this? :-)

Comment: oops! I updated the function. It specifically breaks in the function http://jsfiddle.net/mVLkW/8/ updated it to match a class

Comment: @Lukasz: you have a typo: `myclass` vs `myClass`

Answer (score 2):

`hasClass` should definitely work. You can also check the length of the returned set of elements.

```
if ($(".myClass.visible").length) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed `.`

```
if($(".myClass").is(".visible")) {
  alert("visible");
}
```

Comment: oh sorry, that is what I meant to type. that doesn't seem to work for me either.

Comment: @Lukasz then you should have some other problem. check your console for errors

Comment: @KevinB `is` returns true/false.